# How to do touch and hold in iOS app using Python client for Appium

Tags: python, ios, selenium-webdriver, appium

We are trying to write an automated test for our iOS app using the Appium python client. 
We want to imitate Swipe event on an element but none of the APIs from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action seem to be behaving the way we want.
Basically we want to break  down swipe in three events (KEYDOWN, MOVE, KEYUP). 
The flow goes as below

1. Find the element.
2. Hold it, swipe it from point A to B and Hold it there. (KEYDOWN and MOVE)
3. Do something.
4. Do something more.
5. Release the element. (KEYUP)

   - How can we achieve it on iOS ?

We have it working on Android using monkeyrunner. It works as below

```
X=50
Y=50
hr = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(timeout = 60, deviceId = dev_2)
hr.touch(X, Y,MonkeyDevice.DOWN)
for i in range(1, 13):
    hr.touch(X, Y + 20*i, hr.MOVE)
    time.sleep(0.1)
MonkeyRunner.sleep(2)

// Do something

hr.touch(X, Y, MonkeyDevice.UP)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with TouchAction class.

elem= self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("something")
self.touch.tap(elem).Longpress().moveto().perform()

Comment: That's an atomic operation. I can't do anything else until that statement finishes execution.

Answer (score 0):

It is Working for Me using touch action class:

```
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(wd);
            touchAction.longPress(webElement).waitAction().moveTo(x,y).release();
            touchAction.perform();
```